# Can python3.1 scripts be freezed in mac os x using cxfreeze?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I m new to this and i need to freeze python3.1 scripts so that it can be run in other machines which does'nt have  python3.1. CXFREEZE is the one which supports python 3.1 as far as i know. But i could not find any thread saying that freeze is successful for python3.x.

So can anybody tell me will it be done with cxfreeze or i have to choose something else to get my app ready to execute in other machines.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should be able to using cx_Freeze from SVN trunk according to this: http://www.mail-archive.com/cx-freeze-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00522.html

Not many other executable builders for Python support 3.0 yet. cx_Freeze sounds like your best shot.